# How to exclude tables when using pg_dumpall with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

If use `pg_dump`, it has a `--exclude-table-data` option to ignore special table.

But `pg_dumpall` command doesn't has that option. So how to exclude several tables when dump all databases?

Answer (score 5):

The name [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) itself says “dump all”, which means you can't exclude anything. There is no such `pg_cumpall` option available.

Use [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

pg_dumpall is a wrapper that calls pg_dump repeatedly.

perhaps you can shim pg_dump by using a script that inserts the needed options onto the command-line.